# Difference between window.onerror and error event listener

Tags: javascript, web

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) mentions:

> When a resource (such as an <img> or <script>) fails to load, an error event using interface Event is fired at the element that initiated the load, and the onerror() handler on the element is invoked. These error events do not bubble up to window, but (at least in Firefox) can be handled with a single capturing window.addEventListener.

Is there any other cases that triggers `window.addEventListener('error', function(event) { ... })` but not `window.onerror`?

Comment: The quote says that <img> and <script> errors won't even trigger the event you shown here, you'd need to set the `capture`  flag to true: `window.addEventListener('error', function(event) { ... }, {capture: true})`, and it also says that it is Firefox behavior, but not that it is expected to work anywhere else (even though Chrome also fires it).

Comment: As to which case, would produce this, it seems that any element that does emit an ErrorEvent will get caught. So at least link, object, video, audio, iframe.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks I didn't catch the capture point. What I want to know is whether there are other exceptions where an error goes into one handler but not the other.